# HTML/CSS Code not responsive

Tags: html, css

I have this web page that I have created, and it works perfectly fine when I'm on full screen on a browser, but when I change the screen size of the browser to non-full screen the page messes up, the image moves to the left hand side rather than staying in the right. ALSO, how can I add 3 more sets of this below this div class.

How page looks normally:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOVTx.png

How page looks when not in full screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmsH3.png

My HTML:

```
<div class="howitworks">
<img class="imghow" src="https://www.realtyshares.com/media/default/howitworks/signup.png" />
<p class="howitworks"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sit amet laoreet augue. Nulla consectetur purus convallis dolor viverra, sed vehicula dolor sagittis. Sed placerat, tellus vel pretium pharetra, felis metus varius lectus, et varius metus arcu et sapien. Maecenas ac lorem eu metus facilisis laoreet. Sed ullamcorper, lectus sed imperdiet gravida, nisl erat aliquam leo, nec pellentesque diam nunc ut augue. Suspendisse quis massa sit amet nulla posuere vulputate vel quis nisl. Fusce nisl sem, suscipit quis egestas vel, ullamcorper vitae dui.</p>
</img>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.howitworks
{
   width: 984px;
   height: 56px;
   padding: 0 20px;
   text-align: right;

}
img.imghow
{
   display: block;
   float: right;


}
p.howitworks
{
text-align: left;
width: 650px;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with it?

Comment: @Paulpro the image moves to the left hand side

Comment: what's the purpose of adding an </img> tag after the <p>?

Comment: You should use a different class other than `howitworks` for the p tag. Otherwise there could be conflict with the div of the same class name.

Comment: Re sizing here has not effect (see: http://jsfiddle.net/HJLXX/) must be some other CSS or HTML (not included above) that is doing the work.  Can you share more of your code?

Comment: Resizing won't have any effect, the container has a fixed width of 984px.

Comment: I understand. Also if I wanted to add 3 more of these below each other. (Like have 4 sets of this), how can I do it? @AdrianTombu

Answer (score 0):

Responsive says it already. Pixels are not responsive. You'll have to work with percentages.

You should read something about responsive before you go any further.

Anyway. In this fiddle i've shown how percentages work: http://jsfiddle.net/HJLXX/1/

It always stays on the right hand side, and both the p and the img resize when the window resizes.

```
.howitworks {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
}

img.imghow {
    float: right;
    width:30%;
}

p.howitworks {
    text-align: left;
    width: 70%;
}
```